# Javac 1.4:Getting list of default jars

Tags: java, configuration, classpath, default, javac

What I am trying to do is to get default classpath for javac 1.4.

In later versions - javac 1.5, 1.6 - I could just create an empty file and run:

`$ javac Foo.java -verbose`

and grab the whole list of jars from the output:

`[parsing completed 108ms]
[search path for source files: .]
[search path for class files: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\jre\lib\resources.jar,C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\jre\lib\rt.jar,C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\jre\lib\sunrsasign.jar,C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\jre\lib\jsse.jar,C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\jre\lib\jce.jar,C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\jre\lib\charsets.jar,C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\jre\lib\modules\jdk.boot.jar,C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\jre\classes,C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar,C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar,C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar,C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar,.]
[checking Foo]
[wrote Foo.class]`

But with javac 1.4 that command doesn't print search class path at all. The output is too brief:

`[parsing completed 108ms]
[checking Foo]
[wrote Foo.class]`

Could someone please advise how to retrieve default jars paths for javac 1.4?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you should ask in an archaeologist forum…

Answer (score 0):

You have setting up following

To set the classpath for the Windows XP Command Prompt:

1. To Copy this  "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin" there java installation path
2. Select Start -> Control Panel -> System -> Advanced -> Environment Variables -> System Variables -> CLASSPATH. Variables Values ->Paste it.
3. Click the Apply button, then the OK button.

and open Command Prompt and type javac and enter to see.

Comment: So you basically mean that my javac 1.4 is not configured properly and  $CLASSPATH variable must be set properly, right? Even in that case javac -verbose doesn't print any default jars.